# GroupPrincipal.Members.Add(userPrincipal) Throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directoryservices

I have the following C# Code which should add a user to a existing group. Now every time I try to add a user to a group the following error is thrown:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IADsGroup'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{27636B00-410F-11CF-B1FF-02608C9E7553}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Below is the relevant code:

```
// Clearing result message variable before using
    sResult = "";

    bool bGroupMemberOf = false;
    using (PrincipalContext sourceContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomainName))
    {
        try
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(sourceContext, IdentityType.Name, sGroupName);
            if (group.Members.Contains(sourceContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sAccountName))
            {
                sResult += sAccountName + " already member of" + group.Name + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            group.Members.Add(sourceContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sAccountName);
            group.Save();
            group.Dispose();

            sResult += sAccountName + " is now member of " + group.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return  error.Message + "-" + error.Source + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    return sResult;
```

Can somebody tel me what is going wrong here. I can hardly find any reference to the error I receive.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: group.members.add(....) throws the exeception.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to refactor the code slightly to use both `GroupPrincipal` and `UserPrincipal`, like this:

```
try {
   GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.Find....
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Find....

   group.Members.Add( user );
}
```

Does this also throw an exception?

Comment: I refactor the code from your example to the code I supplied. The application is a website on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.  the GUID in the error message belongs to ActiveDS.dll